# Is there a tool that can visually map table relationships in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mapping, relational-database

I'm looking for a tool that can map the relationships in my database in mysql.  I would like something like the view that is generated in MS-SQL Server Management Studio in the 'Show Diagram Pane'.  Does such a thing exist?

I'm in charge of the design of the database and its using rails conventions.  I would not be adverse to specifying relationships by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't [MySQL Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/features-benefits.aspx) have a schema diagram tool?  I think it does. I'm not a diagram guy (much happier with mysqldump output) but I've worked with many people who swear by Toad.

Comment: Just fyi Toad 5.7 for sql server diagram tool "not licensed" making getting toad for diagramming pointless

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the official tool has that?

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.1.html

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) 5.1.16 is buggy on my OS X 10.5.7 system. I found that it does things like crashes and vanishes with no error. Or it will error out when trying to change page size in the print setup.

I also tried running it on Windows XP under VMWare. It seemed more stable and usable there. I was able to reverse engineer a DB and create a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

One year ago I used [DBVis](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) together with Oracle. It believe it also works with MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Altova DatabaseSpy will show them if you are on Windows.  If not, the easiest way is to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA (if you're using v5 or later of MySQL) and check out the key column usage statistics for all the tables.  This is easy to script.

Answer (score -2):

Most MySQL databases still use MyISAM tables, which do not provide foreign key constraints.  Without explicit FKs the best you can do is guess at the relationships between tables.

Comment: Just because RI constraints are not recorded or enforced by MyISAM doesn't mean table relationships don't exist in the logical database design.